# NonEmpty set in Haskell

Tags: haskell, containers

Is there an equivalent of Data.Lists.NonEmpty for sets?

I know there is NonNull from mono-traversable, but I'm wondering if there's anything else out there.

Answer (score 2):

Not in base, but there does seem to be a package that includes nonempty versions of a few data structures, such as Maps and Sets.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/non-empty-0.3